# embed youtube video + noscript?

Tags: javascript, youtube, noscript

I'm trying to embed a YouTube video in a `<noscript>` section of my page. Basically, it's a video showing the user what he misses out on.
For some reason though it just doesn't work. All I see is a black rectangle with nothing inside. This happens both in firefox and IE.
Another strange thing is that if I actually go to youtube.com, all videos seem to work just fine.

So why doesn't this work? Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved - If you choose to use "Old embed code" than the embeded object doesn't use JavaScript.
It also uses the old style player, which kinda sucks.

Comment: Maybe - just maybe - i'ts worth the effort using a third party player (and hosting the video) or even making your own.